# JavaScript trigger multiple events but handle once

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, eventtrigger

I don't know if I'm the first one to hit this issue and not wanting to move on but it seems to me that it should have been experienced by others. Also, don't mind the code because I'm writing it up for this example. The actual application is similar in idea.

Let's say you have the following object that controls a certain model:

```
var model = $({
    name: 'user',
    age: 30,
    sex: 'male'
});

model.on( 'namechange agechange sexchange', function ( event ) {
    console.log( 'Model experienced a ' + event.type );
});

model.triggerHandler( 'namechange' );
```

The output of the above code would be `Model experienced a namechange`.

If I wanted to trigger multiple events, the code would look like:

```
model.triggerHandler( 'namechange' );
model.triggerHandler( 'agechange' );
model.triggerHandler( 'sexchange' );
```

And the output would be repeated accordingly.

But what I really want is to have the handler be triggered once when the trigger method triggers one or more of the events to which the handler is bound.

```
model.triggerHandler( 'namechange agechange' ); // hander is bound to both but called once
model.triggerHandler( 'agechange' ); // hander is bound to one and called once
model.triggerHandler( 'namechange carchange agechange' ); // hander is bound to two of the three but called once
```

I do understand the technical limitations due to the way even subscription works. The implementation would have to figure out who is subscribed to all of those events, join the result, and post the event. More so, event.type is not designed to represent a single event name.

Yet I am convinced that there are use cases for such requirements. In my case, it is a dynamic metrics widget dashboard. There is a metrics structure that represents various metrics. Different metrics update on different intervals. Different widgets rely on multiple metrics. When a metric(s) are fetched from the server, I want to trigger an event for each metric change. Widgets will refresh their data. However, I don't want a widget that relies on multiple metrics to refresh multiple times. Instead, I want the handler to be fired once notifying which of that widget's metrics have changed (this filters out metrics that do not relate to the widget from coming into the handler).

I realize that I can make a `metrics.update` event and pass an array of metrics that have changed. In the handler, I could then figure out whether this even concerns the widget. But ideally, I want to avoid this step.

One thought was to define a jquery plugin to buffer events that would use predefined "magic" protocol:

```
model.bulkTriggerHandler( 'namechange agechange' );
```

Plugin `bulkTriggerHandler` could parse the event string and consider event scopes, it could then iterate over the internal objects and figure out to which events they are subscribe using (very hackish) `$._data( object, "events" )` method, aggregate for each object their respective list of related events, and trigger a certain event handler. This bulk event handler would have to be assigned via `model.on( 'bulkUpdate' )`... but that's all very hacky.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any comments, even those that say I should stick to using `metrics.update` and not bother with the above ;)

Comment: Have you considered jquery bind() ?

Comment: No, unless there have been recent revisions to .bind, it works similar to .on method. The problem here is not bind to events but triggering and handing them. You cannot use .trigger( 'eventA eventB' ) but to handle them at once. I just found that a ticket was raised and resolved as 'wontfix' for jquery: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12734.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be wrapping around triggering, you should wrap around event binding. Provide your own function to bind multiple events. It will bind its own handler for the individual events. This function will keep track of which events have occurred, and when all the events in the list occur it will then call the supplied handler function. The caller would call it as:

```
model.multiBind('namechange agechange', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Its not required that all on the bound events are triggered. The above handler should be called when I perform model.triggerHandler('namechange'); and model.triggerHandler('agechange'); and model.triggerHandler('namechange agechange'); calls. Maybe multiBind should bind to the above events and a special 'flush' event and its handler should create a queue of triggered events. To trigger, .multiTrigger should trigger every event it specifies and finish it off with triggering 'flush' event. Flush will let multiBind know that "transaction" has finished and it can distribute the events.

Comment: I guess I misunderstand what you want. You wrote _what I really want is to have one handler be triggered once when multiple changes have occurred_. So I thought you wanted to wait until all the different change events have occurred before running the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is getting a little stale but maybe I can still help...

```
//Define a single function that takes an event object
function handleChange(event)
{
    // Log a string parameterized with event.type
    console.log( 'Model experienced a ' + event.type );
}

// Register handlers one at a time but reuse the function
model.on( 'namechange', handleChange);
model.on( 'agechange', handleChange);
model.on( 'sexchange', handleChange);
```

It **would** be sort of cool to be able to define a handler for N events at a time but this seems to be a way to avoid duplicate code.

You could always write a utility function that takes an array or arbitrary number of positional arguments and does the repeated `.on` for you. I would be called as such:

```
handle(model, ["namechange", "agechange", "sexchange"], handleChange);
```